# Problem solving a partial derivative with a integral.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Good night, i have a serious problem solving this partial derivative:
$f(x,y)=\int_{y}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt$

I don't know how i can start this, please give me a help, don't do it the exercise, only explain me how i can make this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the partial derivatives of $f$? Just use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: i cannot solve the partial derivate, of function $f$. @MatthewKvalheim

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming this is what you are looking for.) For example,

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_y^x e^{t^2}dt=e^{x^2}$$

by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Finding the other partial is very similar.

Comment: Thanks Eliot, but... because $e^{x^{2}}$? for the Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: I would google the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus if you are unfamiliar. The first part of the theorem states that, because $e^{t^2}$ is continuous, we can find the derivative of the integral by basically replacing $t$ with $x$.